# Как перебрать циклом список тегов?

Tags: python, парсер, list, beautiful-soup

Есть вот такой html:

```
<div class="section">
<div class="catalog-music inline_player_playlist">

    <div class="music-popular-wrapper">
        <div class="music-popular__item">
            <div class="popular-play">
                <a class="..."></a>
                <span class="icon-play">
                    ::before
                </span>
                ...
                <div class="popular-play-name">
                    <a class="popular-play-composition" href="/singer/dua+lipa.html" data-pjax-state="">
                        Dua Lipa
                    </a>
                    <span>-</span>
                    <a class="popular-play-author" href="/popsa/*.html" data-pjax-state="">
                        Blow Your Mind
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popular-download"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="music-popular-wrapper">...</div>
    <div class="music-popular-wrapper">...</div>
    <div class="music-popular-wrapper">...</div>
    <div class="music-popular-wrapper">...</div>

    <!-- Абсолютно такая же структура в этих -->
    <!-- div, как показано выше... -->
    <! --только с разными песнями -->
</div>
```

есть вот такой python-код:

```
parsing = soup.find_all("div", class_="music-popular-wrapper")
```

как написано в документации `find_all()` возвращает список, так вот хочу перебрать этот список циклом и результат передать функции для дальнейшей обработки... чтобы перебрать циклом захотел посмотреть что за список этот `find_all()` создает, бац! не смог разобраться что за список он создает...
когда взглянул на этот список увидел там следующую страшилку:

```
parsing[0] - list
[
    0 -> index
    [
        0 -> index
        [],
        1 -> index
        [
            0 -> index
            []
        ]
    ],
]
```

это возможно не правильно! не смог вообще увидеть структуру этого списка... как вообще перебрать такой список ?

и есть ли какая нибудь функция чтобы увидеть структуру таких сложных списков ?

Вообщем, хочу перебрать циклом каждый `<div class="music-popular-wrapper">...</div>` и + дочерних элементов... тоесть каждый такой `<div class="music-popular-wrapper">...</div>` div это элементы списка возвращающая функция `find_all()`

Comment: Скорее всего, это не список. Напишите, что выводит `print(type(soup.find_all(...)))`.

Comment: @wchistow, <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>

Answer (score 0):

Какую IDE вы используете, какую версию Python, [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup)?
Что-то похоже, что проблема у вас не на стороне BS.

Зарядим ваш html из вопроса, и попробуем посмотреть.

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = '''
<div class="section">
<div class="catalog-music inline_player_playlist">

    <div class="music-popular-wrapper">
        <div class="music-popular__item">
…
    <div class="music-popular-wrapper">...</div>

    <!-- Абсолютно такая же структура в этих -->
    <!-- div, как показано выше... -->
    <! --только с разными песнями -->
</div>
'''

soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
parsing = soup.find_all("div", class_="music-popular-wrapper")
print(parsing[0])
```

###### Вывод:

```html
<div class="music-popular-wrapper">
<div class="music-popular__item">
<div class="popular-play">
<a class="..."></a>
<span class="icon-play">
                    ::before
                </span>
                ...
                <div class="popular-play-name">
<a class="popular-play-composition" data-pjax-state="" href="/singer/dua+lipa.html">
                        Dua Lipa
                    </a>
<span>-</span>
<a class="popular-play-author" data-pjax-state="" href="/popsa/*.html">
                        Blow Your Mind
                    </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="popular-download"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Никаких страшилок, выдаёт html код.

> Вообщем, хочу перебрать циклом каждый `<div class="music-popular-wrapper">...</div>` и + **дочерних элементов**... тоесть каждый такой `<div class="music-popular-wrapper">...</div>` div это элементы списка возвращающая функция `find_all()`

Ну а для дочерних элементов есть замечательный [`.children()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) и [`.descendants()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants). Первый выводит непосредственно вложенные теги первого уровня, а второй все вложенные теги рекурсивно.

```python
from bs4 import NavigableString

for child in parsing[0].children:
    if isinstance(child, NavigableString):
        continue
    print(child.name)
```

###### Вывод:

```
div
```

---

```python
for descendant in parsing[0].descendants:
…
```

###### Вывод:

```
div
div
a
span
div
a
span
a
div
```